# First entry in each of the Vectors from a sequence of Vectors of Sets in Scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I have a sequence of Vectors of Sets of Ints. I want the first entry in each of the Vectors. My attempt just gives me each item in the first vector.

```
scala> (1 to 4).map((10 to 13).toSet.subsets(_).toVector)
res112: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Vector[scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int]]] = Vector(Vector(Set(10), Set(11), Set(12), Set(13)), Vector(Set(10, 11), Set(10, 12), Set(10, 13), Set(11, 12), Set(11, 13), Set(12, 13)), Vector(Set(10, 11, 12), Set(10, 11, 13), Set(10, 12, 13), Set(11, 12, 13)), Vector(Set(10, 11, 12, 13)))

scala> (1 to 4).map((10 to 13).toSet.subsets(_).toVector).mkString("\n")
res113: String =
Vector(Set(10), Set(11), Set(12), Set(13))
Vector(Set(10, 11), Set(10, 12), Set(10, 13), Set(11, 12), Set(11, 13), Set(12, 13))
Vector(Set(10, 11, 12), Set(10, 11, 13), Set(10, 12, 13), Set(11, 12, 13))
Vector(Set(10, 11, 12, 13))

scala> (1 to 4).map((10 to 13).toSet.subsets(_).toVector).take(1).mkString("\n")
res114: String = Vector(Set(10), Set(11), Set(12), Set(13))

scala> (1 to 4).map((10 to 13).toSet.subsets(_).toVector).head.mkString("\n")
res115: String =
Set(10)
Set(11)
Set(12)
Set(13)
```

What I am trying to get is:

```
Set(10) 
Set(10, 11)
Set(10, 11, 12)
Set(10, 11, 12, 13)
```

Comment: You were close enough, you do not want the first entry of the first vector, but rather, the first entry of each vector. That is a **map**, because you are transforming a collection. `(1 to 4).map((10 to 13).toSet.subsets(_).toVector).map(_.head).mkString("\n")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(1 to 4).map((10 to 13).toSet.subsets(_).toVector).flatMap(_.headOption)
```

You were taking the head of the outer vector, not the head of every component of the outer vector. Notice, I use `flatMap` and `headOption` here as it's safer: `head` will crash on an empty collection.

Answer (score 3):

It's easy:

```scala
val vec = (1 to 4).map((10 to 13).toSet.subsets(_).toVector)
val res = vec.map(_.head)
```

`_.head` selects the first element of each `Set`.

As bonus knowledge, `_.tail` would select everything but the head of each `Set`.

[Try it out!](https://scalafiddle.io/sf/HTpEaSE/0)

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

You were close enough, you do not want the first entry of the first vector, but rather, the first entry of each vector. That is a **map**, because you are transforming a collection.

```
val vectors = (1 to 4).map((10 to 13).toSet.subsets(_).toVector)
val firstSets = vectors .map(_.head)

firstSets.mkString("\n")
// Set(10)
// Set(10, 11)
// Set(10, 11, 12)
// Set(10, 11, 12, 13)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `scanLeft`:

```
(10 to 13).scanLeft(Set.empty[Int])((a,b)=> a + b ).tail.mkString("\n")
```

On the console:

```
scala> (10 to 13).scanLeft(Set.empty[Int])((a,b)=> a + b ).tail.mkString("\n")
res41: String =
Set(10)
Set(10, 11)
Set(10, 11, 12)
Set(10, 11, 12, 13)
```